# Add column with cte containing parent of one level up

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have the following code in a View that works well and gives the required output.

```
;WITH ctesample 
     AS (SELECT sjob, 
                mjob, 
                mjob AS DisplayMJob, 
                groupf, 
                0    AS LVL 
         FROM   dbo.vw_jobcosting_wipmastersub 
         WHERE  ( groupf = 'True' ) 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub_1.sjob, 
                vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub_1.mjob, 
                CASE S.lvl 
                  WHEN 0 THEN S.sjob 
                  ELSE S.displaymjob 
                END       AS DisplayMJob, 
                vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub_1.groupf, 
                S.lvl + 1 AS Expr1 
         FROM   ctesample AS S 
                INNER JOIN dbo.vw_jobcosting_wipmastersub AS 
                           vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub_1 
                        ON S.sjob = vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub_1.mjob 
         WHERE  ( vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub_1.groupf = 'False' )) 
SELECT sjob, 
       CASE 
         WHEN displaymjob IS NULL THEN sjob 
         ELSE displaymjob 
       END AS MJob, 
       groupf 
FROM   ctesample AS cteSample_1
```

I need to add one more column that gives the parent of the output MJob (not the sorce data MJob) for each record.

Source data is in the following form:

```
╔═════════════════════════╗
║ SJob,MJob,GroupF        ║
╠═════════════════════════╣
║ 10001000,NULL,True      ║
║ 10001001,NULL,True      ║
║ 10001002,NULL,True      ║
║ 20001000,10001000,True  ║
║ 20001001,10001001,True  ║
║ 20001002,10001001,True  ║
║ 20001003,10001002,True  ║
║ 30001000,20001000,False ║
║ 30001001,20001000,False ║
║ 30001002,20001001,False ║
║ 30001003,20001002,False ║
║ 30001004,20001002,False ║
║ 30001005,20001003,False ║
║ 30001006,20001003,False ║
║ 30001007,30001000,False ║
║ 30001008,30001000,False ║
║ 30001009,30001001,False ║
║ 30001010,30001002,False ║
║ 30001011,30001002,False ║
║ 30001012,30001003,False ║
║ 30001013,30001004,False ║
║ 30001014,30001005,False ║
║ 30001015,30001006,False ║
║ 30001016,30001006,False ║
╚═════════════════════════╝
```

I don't know how to tackle it.
Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Required output is below:

```
Sjob,Mjob,OutputMJob,GroupF
10001000,NULL,NULL,TRUE
10001001,NULL,NULL,TRUE
10001002,NULL,NULL,TRUE
20001000,10001000,NULL,TRUE
20001001,10001001,NULL,TRUE
20001002,10001001,NULL,TRUE
20001003,10001002,NULL,TRUE
30001000,20001000,10001000,FALSE
30001001,20001000,10001000,FALSE
30001002,20001001,10001001,FALSE
30001003,20001002,10001001,FALSE
30001004,20001002,10001001,FALSE
30001005,20001003,10001002,FALSE
30001006,20001003,10001002,FALSE
30001007,20001000,10001000,FALSE
30001008,20001000,10001000,FALSE
30001009,20001000,10001000,FALSE
30001010,20001001,10001001,FALSE
30001011,20001001,10001001,FALSE
30001012,20001002,10001001,FALSE
30001013,20001002,10001001,FALSE
30001014,20001003,10001002,FALSE
30001015,20001003,10001002,FALSE
30001016,20001003,10001002,FALSE
```

Comment: What does it mean "parent of the output MJob" in your db structure?

Answer (score 0):

The question wasn't completely clear to me, but from what I understand you want something like this:

```
;WITH ctesample 
     AS (SELECT sjob, 
                mjob, 
                mjob AS DisplayMJob, 
                groupf, 
                0    AS LVL, 
                NULL outputMjob 
         FROM   dbo.vw_jobcosting_wipmastersub 
         WHERE  ( groupf = 'True' ) 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub_1.sjob, 
                vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub_1.mjob, 
                CASE S.lvl 
                  WHEN 0 THEN S.sjob 
                  ELSE S.displaymjob 
                END       AS DisplayMJob, 
                vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub_1.groupf, 
                S.lvl + 1 AS Expr1, 
                S.mjob 
         FROM   ctesample AS S 
                INNER JOIN dbo.vw_jobcosting_wipmastersub AS 
                           vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub_1 
                        ON S.sjob = vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub_1.mjob 
         WHERE  ( vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub_1.groupf = 'False' )) 
SELECT sjob, 
       CASE 
         WHEN displaymjob IS NULL THEN sjob 
         ELSE displaymjob 
       END AS MJob, 
       groupf, 
       outputmjob 
FROM   ctesample AS cteSample_1
```

A working example can be found on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/01177/5).
Please let me know if this isn't exactly what you asked about and I'll try to give you a better answer.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't really clear. That is close to what I need, but not quite. Using your example, OutputMJob should always be the parent of MJob.

Comment: So can you try to add some details so that it is clear please?

Comment: I am having a little trouble expressing what I need, have mocked up the output I am after. I hope this makes it a little clearer.

Comment: @user2849560, mocked it up where?

Comment: Sorry, posted to early. Here it is.

Comment: As an edit to the original question. I keep hitting enter to early.